# save the selected options rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

I have one Rally Sdk2 app, which has chooserDialog box.
Which displays programs, I can select multiple programs and click filter
then it displays the features for those programs but, when I again came to same dialog it does not store the last choices I made..
I tried stateful, but I am not getting it correct, below is my Dialog

[image]

And below is my ChooserDialog code

```
            _run: function() {
                var me = this;
                Ext.create('Rally.ui.dialog.ChooserDialog', {
                    width: 470,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    height: 500,
                    title: 'Select to Filter',
                    pageSize: 100,
                    closable: false,
                    selectionButtonText: 'Filter', 
                    itemId: 'chooser',
                    multiple: true, 
                    setMultiple: true,
                    artifactTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Program','PortfolioItem/Epic','PortfolioItem/MMF'],
                    autoShow: true,
                    stateful: true,
                    stateId: 'selected-pi',
                    stateEvents: ['click','statesave'],
                    storeConfig:{
                        fetch: ['Name','PortfolioItemTypeName', 'Parent']
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        scope: me,
                        artifactChosen: function(selectedRecord) {
                            //this.down('#chooser').setValue(selectedRecord);
                            var filters = me._getFilters(selectedRecord);
                            me._drawCardBoard(me, filters);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be possible in the rc builds of the SDK.  We just made the new 2.0 version available and it has full support for the stateful mixin now.

There is even a guide for how to implement it:

http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/state

Also please note that the ChooserDialog is considered deprecated.  The [ArtifactChooserDialog](http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.dialog.ArtifactChooserDialog) should be a mostly drop-in replacement however.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but as I specified above not working when multiple options selected.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try State, but `localstorage` can be used to set default values:

```
localStorage.setItem('MyComboboxValue',Ext.getCmp('MyCombobox').getValue());
```

and get default values by setting `value` config property of the component to the value returned by:

```
value: localStorage.getItem('MyComboboxValue')
```

See a full code example of saving selections in comboboxes and checkboxes via localstorage in [this github repo](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/saving-selections-in-apps-with-localstorage). The choices are retained after the page is reloaded.

UPDATE: I tried to make ArtifctChooserDialog remember selections, but it turns out that this code will not work in case of multiple selections when `multiple: true` due to a bug that Kyle identified.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    _selected: [],
    stateful: true,
    getState: function(){
        return{
            selectedRef: this.selectedRecord
        }
    },
    launch: function() {
        var that = this;
        Ext.create('Rally.ui.dialog.ArtifactChooserDialog', {
            itemId: 'dialog',
            autoShow: true,
            multiple: true,
            artifactTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Theme','PortfolioItem/Initiative','PortfolioItem/Feature'],
            storeConfig:{
                fetch: ['Name','PortfolioItemTypeName']
            },
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                artifactchosen: function(dialog, selectedRecord) {
                    this._selected.push(selectedRecord);
                    console.log(selectedRecord);
                    //this.selectedRecord = dialog.getSelectedRef();
                    this.selectedRecord = Rally.util.Ref.getRelativeUri(selectedRecord);
                    this.saveState();

                }
            },
            selectedRef: this.selectedRef
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks nick for the reply, yes it is not working for mulitple options. By defining global variables I am able to keep track of selected choices, but not able to show them selected in ChooserDialog

Comment: we have been able to repro the defect and will have a fix soon.  i will post back once the fix has been incorporated into the 2.0 release- likely the first week in february.